# SQL - Multiple Clause

Tags: sql

I am having an issue with this query that I am trying to write.

**Example table**

`Table1`:

```
ID   | Type  
--------------------
111  | beer  
111  | Wine  
222  | Wine  
333  | Soda
```

I am trying to query those who bought wine but didn't buy beer.

I am at

```
select ID
from table1
where type <>'beer' 
and   type = 'wine'
```

which does not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is just table of drinks. Where do you keep those who bought a drink? I assume you will need to join more tables here.

Comment: the ID is what we will call "purchase ID" so it would be the people who bought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for records in your table where the type is not beer but wine. This is not what you want. You should be looking for IDs where records exist or not.

Usually you would have a persons table associated:

```
select *
from persons
where id in (select id from table1 where type = 'wine')
and id not in (select id from table1 where type = 'beer');
```

or with exists

```
select *
from persons
where exists (select * from table1 where id = persons.id and type = 'wine')
and not exists (select * from table1 where id = persons.id and type = 'beer');
```

Without a persons table you would simple select IDs:

```
select id
from table1 wine_buyers
where type = 'wine'
and not exists (select * from table1 where id = wine_buyers.id and type = 'beer');
```

or

```
select id
from table1 
where type = 'wine'
and id not in (select id from table1 where type = 'beer');
```

Some dbms offer set methods:

```
select id from table1 where type = 'wine'
minus
select id from table1 where type = 'beer';
```

EDIT: Just thought I should add a way where you scan the table just once. You'd kind of create a flag for wine and beer per id:

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having max(case when type = 'wine' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
and max(case when type = 'beer' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id 
FROM table1
WHERE type = 'wine' 
AND id NOT IN
    (SELECT id 
    FROM table1
    WHERE type = 'beer');
```

The nested query selects those who have purchased beer. The outer query selects those who have purchased wine but do not have their id in the list of those who have purchased beer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ID
from table1 as t1
left join tabel1 as t2 on t1.id=t2.id
    and t2.type ='beer'
where t1.type = 'wine'
and t2.id is null
```